# Null constraint error while updating existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an existing table `vault` in my database, which has some data in it. I now added a new column to the table, `is_master` which tells whether some vault is a master vault or not. The SQL that I used was:

```
ALTER TABLE vault ADD COLUMN is_master BOOLEAN NOT NULL;

UPDATE vault
    SET is_master = (name = 'Master');
```

However, after running this migration against my existing database, I'm getting some null constraints errors and I can't figure why.

```
ERROR: column \"is_master\" contains null values
```

Could someone help me understand what's wrong?

Comment: Do you have rows with NULL in the _name_ column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st add the column with allow null

```
ALTER TABLE vault ADD COLUMN is_master BOOLEAN
```

then do update all the rows

```
UPDATE vault
    SET is_master = name is not null and name = 'Master'
```

then make it not null

```
ALTER TABLE vault
    ALTER COLUMN is_master SET NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You have null entries in your name column. Try the below to filter out null names and then set the values you get from name. You can by default set the values as false while you alter

```
       ALTER TABLE vault ADD COLUMN 
         is_master BOOLEAN NOT NULL
         Set Default FALSE;

      UPDATE vault
       SET is_master = (name = 'Master')
       where name is not null
```

Comment: Which would leave `is_master` as `null` for those rows where name is null

Comment: Aha correct mate i would edit in a while but with the above update query dont you think though all not nulls would be added a value but left ones as you said ismaster left null would get a default data type value